# Meteor.js - Using pathFor with a "foreign key"

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a `Posts` collection where each `Post` in the collection has a `userId` property. On my post detail page, I want to wrap the user's name with a link to their profile using the `pathFor` helper. If I just inlcude `{{pathFor 'userProfile'}}`, it sets up the link with the Post's `_id`, as one would expect, but I obviously need the userId in the link.

I've tried creating a second data context on the template's helper like so, but this didn't work either.

Script:

```
Template.postPage.helpers({
    user: function () {
        return {_id: this.userId};
    }      
});
```

Template:

```
<template name="postPage">
    {{#with user}}<a href="{{pathFor 'userProfile'}}">{{/with}}{{author}}</a>
</template>
```

How would I go about using `pathFor` with the `userId` field from my `Post` doc, instead of the `_id` field from my `Post` doc?

I'm using iron-router if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're getting flummoxed because you're following [Iron Router's example route for `pathFor`](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#path-functions-and-helpers), which looks like this:

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('postShow', {
    path: '/posts/:_id'
  });
});
```

The key here is that `:_id` can be any field. So for your code, try:

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('userProfile', {
    path: '/users/:userId'
  });
});
```

Then the `:userId` in the path corresponds to the `userId` field in your `Post` document.

You also don't need the template helper or the `#with` block. Your template now is just:

```
<template name="postPage">
  <a href="{{pathFor 'userProfile'}}">{{author}}</a>
</template>
```

And the `userProfile` route is sent the entire `Post` document with all its properties, both the document `_id` and the `userId`, and `author` and whatever else is defined. The route knows what to choose because you've told it `:userId` and not `:_id` or `:author` or something else.

Comment: I think he's talking about whatever user made the post, not necessarily the current user.

Comment: Original answer deleted, replaced with more intelligent one :)

Comment: I think this solution has problem when you'll need use it in list of users, because there you'll get user object and there will be _id not userId like in Posts object :/

would suggest just: {{pathFor 'userProfile' _id=userId}}

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you are using iron-router 0.8.0 your pathFor markup should be:

```
<template name="postPage">
  <a href="{{pathFor 'userProfile' params=this}}">{{author}}</a>
</template>
```

Per https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/master/lib/client/ui/helpers.js#L42:

```
/**
 * Example Use:
 *
 *  {{pathFor 'items' params=this}}
 *  {{pathFor 'items' id=5 query="view=all" hash="somehash"}}
 *  {{pathFor route='items' id=5 query="view=all" hash="somehash"}}
*/
```